# MYSQL join and count syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table:articles
id  address     autor   .........
1   name_test1  Paul    ...........
2   name_test2  George  ........
```

This table contains some blog posts.

```
Table:article-hearts
id  cookie_userid   article_id
1   123             1
2   345             1
3   123             2
```

When a visitor click "Heart It!" the action is recorded here.

I want to disply the number of hearts for each blog post.
At this syntax i tried to add a count of hearts:

```
$articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY date_created, time_created DESC ") or die(mysql_error());
```

So it looks like this:

```
 $articles = mysql_query("SELECT a.id, a.address, a.autor, a.date_created, a.time_created, a.title, a.content, a.category, a.reads, ah.cookie_userid, ah.article_id, ah.id, 
COUNT(*) as 'hcount'
FROM
articles AS a
    join 'article_hearts' AS ah where 'ah.article_id' = 'a.id'
    join 'article_hearts' AS ah2 where ah2.article_id=ah.article_id
ORDER BY a.date_created, a.time_created DESC
")or die(mysql_error());
```

I get the error that something is wrong at line 5:join 'article_hearts' AS ah where 'ah.article_id' = 'a.id'

Comment: Remove the quotes arond column and table names

Comment: `article-hearts` vs `article_hearts`. Is there a typo?

Comment: Do not rephrase error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 5 problems :

- Quotes from table
- Joinning a table twice
- Bad syntax of join
- Missing GROUP BY
- You don't need some column in the select

  `$articles = mysql_query(
      "SELECT a.id, a.address, a.autor, a.date_created, a.time_created, a.title, a.content, a.category, a.reads, COUNT(*) as 'hcount'
      FROM articles AS a
      JOIN article_hearts AS ah ON ah.article_id = a.id
      GROUP BY a.id, a.address, a.autor, a.date_created, a.time_created, a.title, a.content, a.category, a.reads
      ORDER BY a.date_created, a.time_created DESC") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I found out that this syntax has another error. If a certain article has "zero hearts' (eg: no value recorded in article-hearts for article_id=1), then the article with id 1 will no longer be displayed in results. Do you have any idea how to fix this? My desperate solution is to make a record in article_hearts for each article i create and then substract 1 from the final output for the hcount :))

Comment: You can use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. After the join must be a `on` condition not a `where considtion. Also you have to remove the single quotes arrond the column names.

```
SELECT a.id, a.address, a.autor, a.date_created, a.time_created, a.title, a.content, a.category, a.reads, ah.cookie_userid, ah.article_id, ah.id, 
COUNT(*) as 'hcount'
FROM
articles AS a
    join 'article_hearts' AS ah on ah.article_id= a.id
    join 'article_hearts' AS ah2 on ah2.article_id=ah.article_id
ORDER BY a.date_created, a.time_created DESC
```